# Solve the system by graphing. y = -3x + 1 y = x -7.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Solve the system by graphing.

$y = -3x + 1$

$y = x -7.$

Which of these coordinates point fits this exact equation?

Step by step process and an explanation to show if it is the correct answer.

$$(-2, 5);~~
(-2, -5);~~
(2, -5);~~
(2, 5)
$$

Comment: "show if it is the correct answer": simply substitute the points into the equations.

Comment: The two equations basically give you two functions you can graph. Maybe you're more familiar with the notation $f(x) = -3x + 1$ and $f(x) = x-7$? (I just substituted $y = f(x)$...) Do you know how to graph these two functions?

Answer (score 2):

This may help you get started:

[image]